# How to find a number of integral solutions (all $x$)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, parametric

If $A$ is between $[1..9000]$
$$A*X = 1 \pmod{9000}$$
All parameters are integers.

I have found some solutions:
$$A = 6907, X = 43,$$
$$A = 7111, X = 991$$

But I don't know how to find all $x$.

I want to know how many of them exist.

Comment: Welcome to MSE , 1.This site uses [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference) for typing the questions.  2. Please have a look  at  ["How to ask a good question"](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)  3. Don't forget to add your own attempts and where did  you get stuck , so  that others  can help you.

Comment: The congruence $ax\equiv 1\pmod{9000}$ is solvable if and only if $\gcd(a,9000)=1$, in which case $x\equiv a^{-1}\pmod{9000}$ (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By [Euler`s Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), if $\gcd(X, A) = 1$, $X \equiv A^{\phi(9000) - 1} \pmod {9000}$, then $XA \equiv 1 \pmod {9000}$, were $\phi(n)$ is the [Euler Totient Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

Therefore the answer is as long as $A$ is coprime to $9000$, $X$ exists. Therefore there are $\phi(9000)$ number of $A$, or $2400$ of them.

Not the best answer, but it is short.

Comment: I strongly recommend you read this: http://wikipediocracy.com/2013/10/20/elementary-mathematics-on-wikipedia-2/